# Errors connecting to an offline cube (.cub) file

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I've been searching for a solution to my doubt but couldn't find anything more relevant than an installation issue, which isn't a problem in my case.

I am trying to execute a C# project (similar to [this](http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2008/06/complete-olap-infrastructure-without_27.html)) that creates a local cube (.cub) file and processes data taken from an existing processed cube on Analysis Services 2012.

The project runs correctly when I use a connection string for output cube that points (and hence writes) to another database on Analysis Services. But when I execute the project using the following connection string that points to the local cube file to be created, it gives me errors depending on the version of ADOMD library referenced.

```
conn.ConnectionString = 
string.Format( "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source={0}", "c:\\output\\mycube.cub" );
```

When referenced to ADOMD 11 library, I get the following errors:

> 1. OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>      to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>      instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>      remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.;
>      08001; Client unable to establish connection; 08001; Encryption not
>      supported on the client.; 08001.
> 2. Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'DB_NAME', Name of
>      'DB_NAME'.

When referenced to ADOMD 12 library, I get the following error:

> A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running.

Although, I know SQL Server Analysis Services are running when I checked in services.msc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was missing a reference to the assembly `Microsoft.AnalysisServices.dll`